# Unity3D glTF Invalid array at buffers when loading a 3d object

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, gltf

I'm using the glTF Unity3D Loader. I want to load some 3D Objects with glTF format in real time. With the glTF files they included in the examples, it works great. But when I try to load my 3D Object I'm getting this error:

Does anyone know how can I approach this?

```
Exception: Invalid array at: buffers
GLTF.Extensions.JsonReaderExtensions.ReadList[Buffer] (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Func`1 deserializerFunc) (at C:/Users/johnmce/Documents/GitHub/UnityGLTF/GLTFSerialization/GLTFSerialization/Extensions/GLTFJsonExtensions.cs:50)
GLTF.Schema.GLTFRoot.Deserialize (System.IO.TextReader textReader) (at C:/Users/johnmce/Documents/GitHub/UnityGLTF/GLTFSerialization/GLTFSerialization/Schema/GLTFRoot.cs:151)
GLTF.GLTFParser.ParseString (System.String gltfContent) (at C:/Users/johnmce/Documents/GitHub/UnityGLTF/GLTFSerialization/GLTFSerialization/GLTFParser.cs:123)
GLTF.GLTFParser.ParseJson (System.Byte[] gltfBinary) (at C:/Users/johnmce/Documents/GitHub/UnityGLTF/GLTFSerialization/GLTFSerialization/GLTFParser.cs:40)
UnityGLTF.GLTFSceneImporter+<Load>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/UnityGLTF/Scripts/GLTFSceneImporter.cs:124)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
```

Comment: Are you using [KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF)? If not, I would give that a try. If yes, then I would (1) test your glTF model in [another viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), and (2) [file a bug on the loader's github repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF/issues/new).

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Well, The solution is that the version of files I was using is 1.1 which isn't supported with the 2.0 parser. So there're many files which the parser can't deserialize, which is unfortunate. Thanks for your time sir. Btw, I've already used the another viewer and filing bugs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Many files that are Version 1.1 aren't supported by the current 2.0 parser.